# what is physical path of File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath?

Tags: windows-7, directory, filesystems, flex4

I am working on `flex desktop application` where i am using this guide from Adobe to save user settings for my application: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/xml_prefs.html

While testing i needed to know the physical path of `File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath` in Windows 7 to check where this file `preferences.xml` being created so i can verify what has written in it, also to test it multiple times by deleting and recreating it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to do that, the path on Windows 7 was found to be here:

```
C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\<FlexProjectDirectoryName>\Local Store
```